# IF statement when check box is NOT selected JQUERY

Tags: jquery, function, selector

I have an if statement where I want to say `IF` a check box is NOT checked and the div has a class of `checkBoxID`, run the function.

The problem I have is how to use the `:not` selector with `this`

`$(this:not(:checked))` does not work. I would like to know if there is a way to use the `:not` selector in the same manor as you would when running a function when a check box IS selected.

Here is my current function below.

```
if ($(this).is(':checked') && $('div').hasClass(checkBoxID))
            {
                // do something..
            }
```

So just to clarify, this current function works when the check box is checked, I want it to work in the opposite direction when the check box is NOT clicked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
{
//..
}
```

Comment: win. thanks a lot. I was thrown by the :not selector and assumed this would be the answer! thanks a bunch Iszk!

Comment: I recommend to use `!this.checked`, because it's more efficient, and does the same job.

Answer (score 1):

use is like `.is`

```
$(this).not(":checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to re-iterate, AndreasAL answered this as well.

```
$(this:not(:checked))
```

will not work because the syntax is wrong, it should be

```
$(this.not(:checked))
```